# HTTP status 500 when using file upload with freemarker

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to add an image upload in my freemarker page(ftl file) using spring and hibernate technology -
this is the error I had every time I run the application :

> HTTP Status 500 - The server
>   encountered an internal error () that
>   prevented it from fulfilling this
>   request.

and this is the code:

1-POM file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2-app-config.xml :

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

3-ftl file :

```
<input type="file" id="image" name="image" value="">
```

4-web controller :

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(Model model , HttpServletRequest req , HttpSession session,@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException{

    // transfer the uploaded image to the place where images exist in project 
    multipartFile.getBytes();
    File destination = new File("/home/user/Pictures/" + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
    multipartFile.transferTo(destination);


    // delete the original uploaded image
    destination.delete();


    return "redirect:index";

}
```

Comment: Can you post some more error logs?

Comment: Yeah, we need the error logs on the server.  If it is a freemarker problem, from my experiences, the error logs are very helpful.

Comment: There is no exceptions or error log appear just : "HTTP Status 500 - The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request." appear in browser .. I don't know where is the problem really .

Comment: How can I get the error log ??

Comment: Is there anyone knows anything that can help me

Comment: This is in no way related to FreeMarker.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to follow the [Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-forms) to the letter. Typically, did you define your `<form>` element correctly, with its `enctype` attribute?

```
<form method="post" action="/form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

For more hints, logs are needed, as other comments have already said. If no specific log is written, then be sure to configure your logger's threshold to a lower level; though a 500 code should be related to an ERROR-level log, which is rarely filtered out. Double-check your log configuration!  :)

HTH

Comment: +1, our trainee had the same issue and this was the solution!
btw, nothing in the logs either (WebLogic 10.3)